# Async Await mongoDb always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this is my async function

```
   async duplicate_email(db, email) {
        await db.collection("users").findOne({ 'email': email }, function(findErr, result) {
            console.log(findErr)
            if (!result) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        });
    }
```

I call it like this from another file :

```
 middleware.duplicate_email(db, "admin@admin.com").then((answer) => {
        console.log(answer)
    });
```

answer always returns undefined, while result is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize the async/await promise syntax by setting the mongo call equal to a variable. Something like this:

```
async duplicate_email(db, email) {

   let myResults;
   try {
     myResults = await db.collection("users").findOne({ 'email': email });
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
   return myResults ? true : false;
 }
```

You can then consume the promise returned by `duplicate_email`

```
middleware.duplicate_email(db, "admin@admin.com").then((answer) => {
    console.log(answer)
});
```

That's the beauty of using async / await. You no longer need the callbacks. However, for error trapping, you'll need the `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot , SilencedoGood, It's great to be aable to count on you on theses kind of problems !

Answer (score 0):

```
async duplicate_email(db, email) {
   let availableEmail =  await db.collection("users").findOne({ 'email': email }) 
       
        if (!availableEmail) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    });
}
```

if you are using async function then dont use callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind answer, it 's so glad to be able to count on your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an short solution

Just return the result and invert it twice. You will get either `true` or `false`

```
async duplicate_email(db, email) {
    try {
       return !!(await db.collection("users").findOne({ 'email': email }))
    }catch(err) {
       console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I really appreciate it, It is working now !